# Is there a problem with my code? Finding null pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, crash, set, fatal-error

I have developed an app login page. The app runs fine, but then crashes halfway through installation. I am new to app development, and aware this is a novice problem. I have looked at the logcat, it does state Java. lang. null pointer Exception, which from my understanding means I have clarified an object which I have called upon in my code. Would you mind pointing out, what exactly I have missed. With thanks.

Again it is not fully running, and the app will not install on my phone. Looking at the logcat it also makes a statement. `Void android. widget. Button. set on.clicklistener(androidview.onclick listener).` I have tried to add to the code setcontent.view equation, but that only seemed to cause errors.

Here is my code.

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText eName;
    private EditText ePassword;
    private Button eLogin;
    private TextView eAttemptsInfo;
    private final String Username = "Admin";
    private final String Password = "12345678";
    Boolean isValid = false;
    private int counter=5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(counter);
        eName = findViewById(R.id.etname);
        ePassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        eLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        eAttemptsInfo = findViewById(R.id.tvAtemptsinfo);

        eLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String inputName = eName.getText().toString();
                String inputPassword = ePassword.getText().toString();

                if (inputName.isEmpty() || inputPassword.isEmpty())


                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter all details correctly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {

                    isValid = validate(inputName, inputPassword);
                    if (!isValid)

                        counter--;
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect details entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    eAttemptsInfo.setText("No. of attempts remaining = "+counter);

                    if (counter == 1) {

                        eLogin.setEnabled(false);
                    {
                    }


                        {

                        }



                    } else

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login was sucessfull.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Add the code to go to new activity
                    Intent intent=new Intent(  MainActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    {

                    }


                }


            }

            private boolean validate(String name, String password) {
                return name.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not an Android expert but this `Looking at the logcat it also makes a statement.` is almost certainly incomplete.  More from the error message / log file would probably help greatly.

Comment: `logcat, it does state Java. lang. null pointer Exception` I didn't see any comments in the code you posted so please indicate the exact line in your code that has this problem, and post the full stack trace of this exception.

Comment: Also, this is not valid Java: `Public class MainActivity`  "Public" should not be capitalized.  Please check the code in question and make sure you have copied and pasted it *exactly* as it appears in your editor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Not sure what part of the code is the problem tbf,

Comment: Not sure which line  of code is causing he error tbf, There is a list of things in the logcat to which it goes into detail[i did try to cut and paste it didn't work. ] one line" Caused by java. long.null pointer exception;Attempt to  invoke virtual method void. android. widget. button.setonlcicklistener.